# MACHINE ?= "beaglebone" core-image-sato

Tags: yocto, beagleboard

i am trying to do the beaglebone black with `core-image-sato` build using yocto project version 4.0.16 (kirkstone). I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS

The build `MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"`, and then I encountered an ERROR during the process. The error is related to `core-image-sato-1.0-r0 do_rootfs`, and the details are attached below.

[image: error]

The logfile shows this error:
update-rc.d: /home/swan/yocto/sources/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/init.d/rc.pvr: file does not exist
%post(ti-sgx-ddk-um-1.17.4948957-r38.beaglebone): waitpid(3912896) rc 3912896 status 100
warning: %post(ti-sgx-ddk-um-1.17.4948957-r38.beaglebone) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package ti-sgx-ddk-um

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Just copy and paste the error text here in proper format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that, at the time of this writing, there is a problem with the meta-ti Kirkstone layer on BeagleBone.

You now have several options:

- Wait until TI fixes the Kirkstone meta-ti branch.
- Try to fix the problem yourself, but maybe there are more problems besides the missing RC script.
- Try a different distro, e.g., Yoe, which has BeagleBone support, but there is currently a problem with a UBoot patch (https://github.com/YoeDistro/yoe-distro/issues/888)
- Use an older version of the TI layer and adjust your configs accordingly. I think you then have to use either your own image definition or strip down Sato to get rid of some packages.